# Django/Python - Try/except problem

Tags: python, django, variables

i have code like this:

```
try:
            var = request.POST['var']                                        
except NameError:                
            var = ''
```

Why always code after "except" is executing? Even if `request.POST['var']` exist.

Answer (score 8):

How do you know it is executing? Perhaps `request.POST['var']` is also `''` so you couldn't tell the difference.

Also, the only way that

```
var = request.POST['var']
```

could raise a `NameError` is if `request` doesn't exist.

If `request.POST` doesn't exist, means `POST` doesn't exist as an attribute of `request` thus raising `AttributeError` instead, and if `request.POST['var']` doesn't exist, means `'var'` is not a key of `request.POST` thus raising `KeyError` instead.

---

EDIT:

My guess is that you're not sending a `POST`. But can't know for sure.

Comment: 'var' is definately not epmty - I see it in firebug. When I'm using AtrributeError instead of Name error i see message "Key 'var' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"

Comment: huh, that means there's no `'var'` in `request.POST` - firebug *is not python** , it can't show python memory, python object contents, or anything on the script running on the server, since firebug runs on the browser. You're wrong about your assumption.

Comment: you are mixing up the two 'var's - the 'var' in the stack frame might exist. But it certainly doesn't exist as a key in your POST! that's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the guesswork and replace `NameError` with something like `KeyboardInterrupt`, look at the traceback and you'll know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: This is the best way to find the cause of the problem.  try/except blocks are useful, but they can also hide problems that you want to find.  Take it out of the equation first.  Then, after you've solved the problem, put it back in.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do what you seem to be trying to do might be

```
var = request.POST.get('var', 'some default value')
```

where the second argument to the POST dict's `get` method is the value to return if the key (`'var'` in this case) doesn't exist.  Translating your example exactly would result in:

```
var = request.POST.get('var', '')
```

That way, no `try...except` block or conditional statements are needed.

Comment: Won't help if `request` is undefined which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

what's the result of the following in your case?

```
except NameError, e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
try:
            if request.method == 'POST':
               var = request.POST['var']                                        
except NameError:                
               var = ''
```